# Openshift: Cannot remove php cartridge

Tags: php, openshift, cartridge

I'm trying to remove php cartridge from my openshift application:

`rhc cartridge remove -a test -c php`

Openshift replies saying:

`'php-5.4' cannot be removed`

I can remove mysql cartridge from the same application without a problem.

Stopping the php cartridge first doesn't help

Anybody have any idea how to remove the php cartridge?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't change/remove the web framework cartridge you used when creating your application (see the [User Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Creating_an_Application5.html)). Why not just create a new application based on a new web framework or the DIY cart?

Comment: Ah didn't see that in the userguide...will create a new one. thx!

Comment: *"Why not just create a new application"* Because it has lots more config attached to it. I'd rather keep the application and just recreate the web cartridge.